# How can i prepopulate a webform field before being loaded

Tags: views, webforms

I have a webform field called company name and i want that when the webform is opened it has a prepopulated value i want to do it from code because i will have a dynamic variable. THis is the code i am using.(currently it is not working a the filed is staying empty

[image]

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function investigation_export_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    // Log the form ID being altered.
    \Drupal::logger('investigation_export')->notice('Altering form with ID: @form_id', ['@form_id' => $form_id]);

    // Check if we are dealing with the correct webform.
    if ($form_id === 'webform_submission_investigation_add_form') {
        // Log that the correct webform is being processed.
        \Drupal::logger('investigation_export')->notice('Processing webform with ID: @form_id', ['@form_id' => $form_id]);
        // if you want to conditionally prepopulate the field based on the form's current page.
       
        $current_page = $form_state->get('current_page');
        
        if (isset($form['elements']['company_name_mbr'])) {
            // Log that the field exists.
            \Drupal::logger('investigation_export')->notice('Field company_name_mbr found in form.');

            // Prepopulate the 'letterforsubmission' field with "hello".
            $form['elements']['company_name_mbr']['#default_value'] = 'hello';

            // Log that the field has been prepopulated.
            \Drupal::logger('investigation_export')->notice('Prepopulating field company_name_mbr with "hello".');
        } }
    }




?>
```